# Equal components that conflict with each other (VUETIFY)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, calendar, vuetify.js, conflict

I have a calendar component that I need to repeat in 3 different tabs, the only different information passed to them is the props [here is where they are being imported into the blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykWZj.png).
However, the menu of these components conflicts as the 3 are on the same screen, if I click on the last imported component it will always open in the first component, [here is my menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obDuU.png), soon after, a print of how it looks on the front, each tabs is a menu, when the button is clicked, it opens only in Ciads One tabs [front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnBLB.png)

Is this a conflict between the variables because they are the same? I didn't use any class or id to open these menus, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

solved by swapping bootstrap tabs for vuetify tabs

Comment: You don't need to inform this in the Answer section, you can either edit the question or add a comment that you found the answer. Else, you can also delete the question.